# Are there field theories which are not CFTs but resemble CFTs up to 3 point functions?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

We know that in CFTs the functional form of 2 and 3 point functions are completely fixed by conformal symmetry. So if a given quantum theory is a CFT we know what form the 2 and 3 point functions will take.

My question is if goes the other way round as well? For instance can there be a theory which has the same functional form of 2 and 3 point functions as a CFT, but which is not actually conformally invariant? Can there be such a theory which does not satisfy the Conformal Bootstrap condition for 4 point functions?

I hope the question is clear. If I'm given the functional form of 2 and 3 point functions of a theory (but not the coefficients i.e OPE coefficients) and asked  if this theory will satisfy Conformal Bootstrap conditions, do I have enough data to say one way or the other?

Comment: In CFT, the two- and three-point functions that are simple are those of primary fields. Two- and three-point functions of descendent fields are also fixed by conformal symmetry, but are more complicated. Before discussing correlation functions, you should discuss the structure of the spectrum, in particular whether there is a conformal algebra that allows you to define primary and descendent fields. Having a conformal algebra does not necessarily imply conformal symmetry. (It might be a spectrum-generating algebra.)